# Is there a technical reason why shopping websites don't provide users with a simple binary search?

Tags: frontend-development, ease-of-use

The following two examples show the problem with common search interfaces when there are multiple pages.

**Example**

> « previous 1 2 … 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 … 129 130 next »
>
> https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/18963233-person-place-or-thing-last-letter?order=a&page=122

What happens if I want page 50? I invite you to try it.

---

**Pathological example**

> Here is the display. [image]
>
> https://www.argos.co.uk/list/9-to-12-years-toys/opt/page:6/sort:price/

What if I want page 300? Again I invite you to try.

**A solution using simple binary search**

Use a classic binary search. Always round down.

> < 1 ... 49,50,51 ... 100 >

You click on the ellipsis (or the nearest number) between the limits you are interested in and you see a new selection. So, suppose I want page 80. I click on the right-most ellipsis and get:

> < 51 ... 74,75,76 ... 100 >

Then

> < 76 ... 87,88,89 ... 100 >
>
> < 76 ... 80,81,82 ... 87 >

Then click on 80.

The whole thing takes 4 clicks. It also scales very well (1 million pages would require a maximum of 20 clicks to reach any single page). It can easily be made more intuitive by also allowing clicking on the nearest number to your destination.

**Question**

Is there a technical (or other good) reason that web developers don't use a binary search as I showed? It is a classic algorithm and is easy to implement in a dozen lines of code.

---

**Notes**

*Binary search works on sorted arrays. Binary search begins by comparing the middle element of the array with the target value. If the target value matches the middle element, its position in the array is returned. If the target value is less than the middle element, the search continues in the lower half of the array. If the target value is greater than the middle element, the search continues in the upper half of the array. By doing this, the algorithm eliminates the half in which the target value cannot lie in each iteration.*
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: I get what you are suggesting, however my area of concern would be narrowing down the search in the first place. If there are 100+ pages of results, that tells me the search isn't working very well.

Comment: @DarrylGodden - How do you suggest narrowing the search? Particularly in my first example? I sometimes want to refer back to a previous part of the conversation.

Comment: This isn't really a question that we can provide a solution to. It's a bit too subjective and covered by our [What Not To Ask](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) guide as more of a rant in disguise (*"X sucks, am i right?"*). It might suit a more discussion based site, but not really a Q&A site such as Stack Exchange.

Comment: Well that's too wide ranging for here, I would need to understand the website, product and proposition, but the comment still stands.

Comment: @ JonW - It is more of a plaintive plea than a rant! I did however ask a well-defined question, "Is there a good reason that web developers don't do this?". For all I know there *is* a good reason, in which case I'd like to know what it is.

Comment: @DarrylGodden - Pretty much every shopping site with multiple pages that I have ever visited has this problem. It's especially noticeable when you have cut things down by description but still have a lot of hits. Then if you want to sort by price, the problem is there. If it is worth doing I could find any number of examples.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong, I think Amazon's is particularly poor and they're a global company. It's made more difficult, for them, by have multi sector offerings where, if you were selling cars, make and model really cuts down the results.

Comment: Probably a combination of many users don't know what a binary search is (or designers don't _think_ they will know) and presentation: I suspect clicking on the ellipsis isn't a "normal" thing, so people won't think to do it. Also, without fore-knowledge/training, users probably won't realise that clicking on `51` doesn't just mean "_show page 51_" but _also_ means "_show pages 51 to 100_". With a suitably designed layout, I think the idea could have legs.

Comment: I find a problem at the core of these paged interfaces. How does the user know which page they want? How do I decide that I want page 300? The most common behavior I see with these is to pick a sort that helps, jump to the first or last page, then make guesses at which page shows the thing you're looking for. Its a pain and binary sorting seems to just give you more pages to randomly navigate to.

Comment: @Ken Mohnkern - In most cases you *don't* know that you want page 300. If the items are sorted by price range you know the sort of price range you are looking for. By clicking on the middle page you see whether the price you want is higher or lower. If it's higher you click to the right. If it's lower you click to the left.

Comment: @TripeHound - Of course users don't know the name 'Binary search'. However we often do it naturally. Imagine an old-fashioned printed phone book. You are looking for "Connor, S." No-one starts at page one and reads through every entry page by page until they reach Sarah Connor. Naturally you open the book at an intermediate page and work backwards or forwards from there in chunks - That is a binary search. When it's implemented on a computer, all the complicated stuff happens behind the scenes. The user doesn't have to know anything about it.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I agree it's a good idea (for some use-cases), and – with the right UI "guidance" – could work. I have in the past been frustrated by poor paging controls. The concept should certainly be within the grasp of many users. The problem is getting the "right" UI that overcomes the inertia of "it's not commonly implemented, so people won't know what it is/how to use it, so we won't implement it".

Comment: @ TripeHound - It's a long time since I did any coding, I'm retired now. Maybe I'll write something to demo a proposed interface. However it might be some time, I've never written anything for a web-page!

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - The way you describe it here, it's clear how binary is better than wild guessing.

Comment: The reason this isn't implemented more might be that it's not part of a third-party library that dev teams can grab from.

Comment: Hi Chasly, what you're proposing has been done millions of times, it's a relatively common pattern. As a matter of fact, it's done by one of the most common page navigation plugins in WordPress (see https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/ ). And since WP powers more than 30% of sites in the web, chances are your proposed solution is used by several millions of sites. Anyways, the problem you mention is easily solved with any faceted *search and filtering* using a range for price, it has nothing to do with navigation